# Overriding constructor field when extending another class

Tags: typescript

I'm new to TS and still learning it; so I've faced some problem.

I have two classes -- `A` and `B`. class `B` extends `A` so I want to change type of property `_next`. What is the best solution to this problem?

```
class A {
  private _next: A;
  constructor(key: number, next: A) {
    this._next = next;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  private _next: B; // here's a have a problem
  constructor(key: number, next: B) {
    this._next = next;
  }
}
```

I've tried making some generic Type etc. but it doesn't work.

Comment: Private variables cannot be accessed outside the class, even extended classes. Check out the protected keyword instead

Answer (score 0):

Before `B`'s constructor can use the `this` keyword it needs to call `super()`, like this:

```js
class A {
  private _next: A;
  constructor(key: number, next: A) {
    this._next = next;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  private _next: B;
  constructor(key: number, next: B) {
    super(B);
    this._next = next;
  }
}
```

But keep in mind that private properties are not accessible outside of the specific class code. If a method in `B` changes `this._next` that's a separate property than `A`'s `_next` property.

You might instead want to try

```js
class A<Next extends A> {
  constructor(key: number, readonly next: Next) { }
}
```

This makes the `next` property a public, read-only property and gets at what you appear to be trying to do.

**However**, think carefully about what you're trying to do. You'll probably be better off if, instead of a `next` property, you have an iterable container that does that for you like an array or implementing a "linked list" class. Unless your code won't need to be updated/maintained (e.g. school assignment), separating the collection-related code from the non-collection-related code will make your life easier in the long run.